# When reading an object from a parcel in Android, when we not want to use the default ClassLoader?

Tags: java, android, parcelable, parcel

When implementing the Parcelable interface, the CREATOR implementation typically uses a constructor that takes in a Parcel e.g.

```
public Foo(Parcel parcel)
```

In this parcel, we might have code like

mMyField = parcel.readParcelable(MyFoo.class.getClassLoader())

As far as I can tell, it's usually ok to just use the default class loader and pass in null instead since parcel.writeParcelable(mMyField) already stores the class name in the parcel.

So my question is, when would I need to use MyFoo.class.getClassLoader() instead of passing in null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a `Parcel` stores info about its class, but not the class itself, that class will be loaded from a name, like `java/util/ArrayList`. If your class is nt on the classpath or the `.class` file is on a remote server even you will need to use a different ClassLoader that can access it, for example `URLClassLoader`.

Comment: I've been able to pass in a random class loader from an unrelated class (e.g. String.class.getClassLoader()) and readFromParcelable still works. Does Foo.class.getClassLoader() return the same default class loader for every class?

Comment: @CharlesMa No, it gets the classloader that loaded that class. String just got loaded by the default class loader(as would most in `java.lang`), so if you load FooClass from a classloader that can't load all of the classes you need, loading will fail.

Comment: Ah ok, makes sense. I think the default class loader works for my purposes. Thanks